# "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error while iterating through nested dictionary with numeric key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

My dictionary is as shown below. This dictionary is stored in the variable 'api'. I have used only an excerpt of the dictionary as the whole dictionary is very big and follows similar format.

```
{
   "sitedata":[
      {
         "info":{
            "source":"https://thevirustracker.com/"
         }}],
         "countryitems":[{
                  "1":{
         "ourid":1,
         "title":"Afghanistan",
         "code":"AF",
         "source":"https://thevirustracker.com/afghanistan-coronavirus-information-af",
         "total_cases":2335,
         "total_recovered":310,
         "total_unresolved":0,
         "total_deaths":68,
         "total_new_cases_today":0,
         "total_new_deaths_today":0,
         "total_active_cases":1957,
         "total_serious_cases":7         },
                 "2":{
         "ourid":2,
         "title":"Albania",
         "code":"AL",
         "source":"https://thevirustracker.com/albania-coronavirus-information-al",
         "total_cases":782,
         "total_recovered":488,
         "total_unresolved":0,
         "total_deaths":31,
         "total_new_cases_today":0,
         "total_new_deaths_today":0,
         "total_active_cases":263,
         "total_serious_cases":4         },
                 "3":{
         "ourid":3,
         "title":"Algeria",
         "code":"DZ",
         "source":"https://thevirustracker.com/algeria-coronavirus-information-dz",
         "total_cases":4154,
         "total_recovered":1821,
         "total_unresolved":0,
         "total_deaths":453,
         "total_new_cases_today":0,
         "total_new_deaths_today":0,
         "total_active_cases":1880,
         "total_serious_cases":22         },
                 "4":{
         "ourid":4,
         "title":"Angola",
         "code":"AO",
         "source":"https://thevirustracker.com/angola-coronavirus-information-ao",
         "total_cases":30,
         "total_recovered":11,
         "total_unresolved":0,
         "total_deaths":2,
         "total_new_cases_today":0,
         "total_new_deaths_today":0,
         "total_active_cases":17,
         "total_serious_cases":0         },
                 "5":{
         "ourid":5,
         "title":"Argentina",
         "code":"AR",
         "source":"https://thevirustracker.com/argentina-coronavirus-information-ar",
         "total_cases":4532,
         "total_recovered":1292,
         "total_unresolved":0,
         "total_deaths":225,
         "total_new_cases_today":0,
         "total_new_deaths_today":0,
         "total_active_cases":3015,
         "total_serious_cases":157         },
             .
             .
             .
                                   "stat":"ok"
        }]}
```

I am trying to iterate through this dictionary to fetch the country names using the below code:

---

```
api_request = requests.get('https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTotals=ALL')

api = json.loads(api_request.content)

dict = api['countryitems'][0]

for key in dict:

    country = api['countryitems'][0][key]['title']
    print(country)
```

---

But I am getting the error "**TypeError: string indices must be integers**".

Can someone please advise what exactly is going wrong here.
I am using this code on Python 3.7 (Tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

- When iterating through the dictionary it comes to a key called "stat" and its value is just "ok" and it's type String. But all the other elements of the dictionary contain another dictionary as below,

[image]

- So here you have tried to access an element called ['title'] and it will throw the above error.
- Again, I have removed unicode characters from the dictionary too by the
  adding below line additionally,

```
import ast

api = {}
api_request = requests.get('https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTotals=ALL')

api = json.loads(api_request.content)
api = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(api))
```

- Here is my answer,

Sample code as below,

```
import requests
import json
import ast

api = {}
api_request = requests.get('https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTotals=ALL')

api = json.loads(api_request.content)
api = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(api))

dict = api['countryitems'][0]


for key in dict:
    if (str(key).isdigit()):
        country = dict[key]['title']
        print (country)
```

Comment: I have exactly the same thing. My bad, I should have mentioned that the variable 'api' stores the dictionary. My code and the code that you have suggested are exactly the same. Still, the error. Thanks!

Comment: @Aki I changed my answer after you edit your code. Check this will work for you!

Comment: Thank you! I have used something similar to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Aki Is this answer is correct and if it's useful for you, please mark as a correct answer. 
Thanks!